# Relation between primeness and co-primeness of integers

Tags: number-theory, logic, prime-numbers, integers, coprime

I wonder what this stunning formal analogy between the definitions of being **co-prime** (for two integers) and being **prime** (for one integer) might reveal – and how:

> $\alpha, \beta$ are **co-prime** iff
>
> $$(\forall x)\ \alpha|x \wedge \beta|x \leftrightarrow \alpha\beta|x$$
>
> $\alpha$ is **prime** iff
>
> $$(\forall xy)\   \alpha|x \vee \alpha|y \leftrightarrow \alpha|xy$$

Note that and how the two definitions are equivalent modulo swapping

- $\wedge$ and $\vee$ on the left side
- constants and variables on the right side together with
- the direction of divisibility $|$ with respect to the product <sub>[thanks to user Wojowu]</sub>
- <strike>the direction of inference $\rightarrow$</strike> <sub>[thanks to user Roll up and smoke Adjoint]</sub>

Comment: Note you also swap the direction of divisibility. This is an interesting observation, but I don't think there is any "stunning" meaning behind it.

Comment: Note that you can also replace $\rightarrow$ with $\leftrightarrow$ since each of those propositions on either side are in isomorphism with one another.

Comment: There is most likely a nice interpretation in the language of lattices/filters.

Comment: In the poset category for integers dividing one another $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ consists of a single point or is empty.   Let $(X \mid Y)$ denote the nonempty hom-set. Notice that multiplication by an element $\alpha \in \Bbb{Z}$ is a functor from the poset category to itself since $(X \mid Y) \implies (\alpha X \mid \alpha Y)$ and so on proves the functoriality of multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the poset category of integers dividing one another we write sometimes write $\alpha \to x$ instead of $\alpha \mid x$.

The "product" $\alpha \beta$ of two coprime objects $\alpha, \beta$ is such that $\alpha \to \alpha \beta \leftarrow \beta$ and for any object $x$ such that $\alpha \to x \leftarrow \beta$ then there is a unique arrow $\alpha \beta \to x$.  That is precisely the definition of [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct#Definition) in a general category.

Thus when $\alpha, \beta$ are *coprime*, then the category definitely has a *coproduct* for them.

Thus $\wedge$ is encoded in the fact that $\alpha \to x \leftarrow \beta$, ie. both morphisms exist simultaneously.  I believe product is $\gcd(\alpha, \beta)$.

---

Actually, it turns out that the coproduct exists for any two integers and it's $\text{lcm}(\alpha, \beta)$.

---

Primality is difficult because of the $\vee$.  So create a new definition.  An arrow into a coproduct is prime when there exists a morphism into at least one of the coproduct's components such tha the relevant triangle commutes.

Notice we used coproduct here which is $\text{lcm}(\alpha, \beta)$ since the definition of prime is equivalent to $p \mid \text{lcm}(\alpha, \beta) \implies p \mid \alpha \vee p \mid \beta$.

---

So take the contrapositive of that.  $p \nmid \alpha \wedge p \nmid \beta \implies p \nmid \text{lcm}(\alpha, \beta)$.

Form the "negated" poset category of integers *not* dividing one another.  It's formed by mapping each hom-set to $\varnothing$ when it's nonempty and vise-versa, so it's not a functor from the original category.

Answer (score 0):

The second can become:$$(\forall xy)\alpha\mid xy\to\alpha\mid x\lor\alpha\mid y$$ The first is: $$(\forall x)\alpha\beta\nmid x \to \alpha\nmid x \lor \beta\nmid x \lor \alpha\beta \gt x\lor(\alpha,\beta)^2\nmid x$$ Not sure it reveals much though.