# Interesting pairs of properties and relations in ring theory

Tags: logic, ring-theory, definition

*[I'm aware that this question is opinion-based - because it's about "interesting" properties - but I dare to ask it nevertheless. You can replace "interesting" by "important" if you want to – which doesn't make the question less opinion-based.]*

---

I start from the observation that there is a strong [formal analogy between the "interesting" concepts of being prime and of being co-prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982124/relation-between-primeness-and-co-primeness-of-integers):

> $\alpha$ is **prime** iff
>
> $$(\forall xy)\   \alpha|x \vee \alpha|y \leftrightarrow \alpha|xy$$
>
> $\alpha, \beta$ are **co-prime** iff
>
> $$(\forall x)\ \alpha|x \wedge \beta|x \leftrightarrow \alpha\beta|x$$

and that there is presumably an "interesting" relation between the two concepts.

Now I wonder if this might be a general scheme for arbitrary relations $\phi(x,y)$:

If a property **P** defined like this

> $\alpha$ is **P** iff
>
> $$(\forall xy)\   \phi(\alpha,x) \vee  \phi(\alpha,y) \leftrightarrow  \phi(\alpha,xy)$$

is "interesting", then also the relation **co-P** defined like this

> $\alpha, \beta$ are **co-P** iff
>
> $$(\forall x)\ \phi(\alpha,x) \wedge  \phi(\beta,x) \leftrightarrow \phi(\alpha\beta,x) $$

is "interesting", and both relate in an "interesting" way.

If not for every "interesting" property **P**: for which properties? (Examples or a criterion would be welcome.)

But maybe **P** = **prime** with $\phi(x,y) = (\exists z)\ xz = y$ is the only such "interesting" property.

Note that in groups and in fields this relation is **not** interesting because it holds for all $x,y$ (in fields: with $x\neq 0$) and no $x,y$ are co-prime.