# Relation between residues and primitive roots modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

I got a very satisfiying [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983863/1792) to my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982124/relation-between-primeness-and-co-primeness-of-integers) on the relation between primeness and co-primeness of numbers which can be defined in a somehow symmetric way:

> $n$ is prime iff
>
> $$(\forall xy)\   n\ |\ x \vee n\ |\ y \leftrightarrow n\ |\ x\cdot y$$
>
> $n, m$ are co-prime iff
>
> $$(\forall x)\ n\ |\ x \wedge m\ |\ x \leftrightarrow n\cdot m\ |\ x$$

The answer made use of categorical language (as the terms *prime* and *co-prime* suggest), explaining the analogy by products and co-products.

Now I came up with another definitional symmetry, and I'd like to know how it can be "explained", possibly again in a categorical framework:

> - n is a [residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $m$ iff
>
> $$(\exists x < m)\ \operatorname{gcd}(x,m) = 1 \wedge (\exists k)\ x^k \equiv n \pmod{m}$$
>
> - n is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $m$ iff
>
> $$(\forall x < m)\ \operatorname{gcd}(x,m) = 1 \rightarrow (\exists k)\ n^k \equiv x \pmod{m}$$

To ask more pointedly: Are residues some kind of a (categorical) co-concept of primitive roots?

Comment: The "residue" statement looks wrong; basically, I don't think any such statement without a $2$ somewhere in it has any chance to be true. As for the "primitive root" statement, it becomes true if you require $x$ to be coprime to $m$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint concerning primitive roots, I corrected the definition. Note that both "statements" are considered to be *definitions*. What can be *wrong* with the first one? And aren't there - next to quadratic residues - cubic and biquadratic residues (which are residues by my definition)?

Comment: You are defining words that are already defined, so the definitions should be equivalent. The "primitive root" one is now correct. As for the "residues" one, every integer $x$ coprime to $m$ is a residue according to your new definition. Probably not what you want :)

Comment: I just wanted to *restate" the definitions (that admittedly already exist, at least the second one) in a unified manner - to highlight some kind of "syntactical symmetry". That's what it's all about. (Now I have to fix the definition of residues.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: My new definition of "residue" is stronger than the old one, so what you say must hold already for the older, i.e. the weaker one. But probably both are not what I want.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Having convinced myself - by checking some small primes $m$ - I take your comment as an answer: being a residue and being a primitive root cannot be co-concepts of each other because one holds for all $n<m$ while the other one doesn't. Thanks for this answer. (Can you give me a hint how to prove that all $n<m$ are residues?)

Comment: Your definition of "residue" just lets one take $x=n$ and $k=1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg But even when one requires $k>1$ - and that's where residues normally start - your statement seems to hold. What's the proof then?

Comment: $k>1$ won't save you. You can take $k = \phi\left(m\right)+1$ for the same effect (as $x^{\phi\left(m\right)} \equiv 1 \mod m$ for each $x$ coprime to $m$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thanks, that's the argument I was looking for.