# A question concerning higher residues (quadratic and so on)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, quadratic-residues

When $x \equiv a \pmod{n}$ one says that $a$ is the residue of $x$ modulo $n$.

So one can define:

> $a$ is a 1-residue modulo $n$ if there is an $x$ with $x \equiv a
>  \pmod{n}$.

Clearly, every $a<n$ is a 1-residue modulo $n$.

When $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{n}$ one says that $a$ is the quadratic residue of $x$ modulo $n$.

So one can define:

> $a$ is a 2-residue modulo $n$ if there is an $x$ with $x^2 \equiv a
>  \pmod{n}$.

In general:

> $a$ is a k-residue modulo $n$ if there is an $x$ with $x^k \equiv a
>  \pmod{n}$.

And finally

> $a$ is a higher residue modulo $n$ when it is a k-residue modulo
>   $n$ for some $k>1$.

In other words:

> $a$ is a higher residue modulo $n$ when there is a $k>1$ and
>   an $x$ with  $x^k \equiv a \pmod{n}$.

I have learned that

> $a$ is a higher residue modulo $n$ iff it is a 1-residue modulo $n$.

– i.e. every $a < n$ is a higher residue.

An argument, why this is so, was given by Darij Grinberg in a comment to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064823/relation-between-residues-and-primitive-roots-modulo-p). It involves [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi$:

> You can take $k=\varphi(n)+1$ as $x^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$
>   for each $x$ coprime to $n$.

Could anyone please clarify this argument - for me it's too concise.

Comment: That argument only works for those classes prime to $n$.  If, say, you let $n=4, a=2$ there is no $k>1$ for which $x^k\equiv 2\pmod 4$ has a solution.

Comment: @lulu: Which "classes prime to $n$" do you mean? I only know  "numbers coprime to $n$".

Comment: Same thing.  I mean the numbers coprime to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then $a$ is invertible $\pmod n$, by [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).  Indeed the set of residues coprime with $n$ form a group under multiplication $\pmod n$.  By definition the order of that group is $\varphi(n)$.  It follows from basic group theory that $\gcd(a,n)=1\implies a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$  whence that $a^{\varphi(n)+1}\equiv a\pmod n$

Note, however, that this argument only applies to residue classes prime to $n$.  The claim you assert isn't true generally.  For example, let $n=4,a=2$.  We claim that, for $k>1$, the congruence $x^k\equiv 2\pmod 4$ has no solution.  Indeed, we just go case by case.  if $x\equiv 0 $ then $x^k\equiv 0$, if $x\equiv 1$ then $x^k\equiv 1$, if $x\equiv 2$ then $x^k\equiv 0$ (since $k>1$), and if $x\equiv 3$ then $x^k\equiv (-1)^k\not \equiv 0$.